# find the appropriate regular expression

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

Can you help me to find the right Regular expression to extract (`Margaux` or `Saint-Julien`) in each time of this 2 pages:

in [page 1](http://www.nicolas.com/index.php/fr/18_17_9674.htm): `Margaux, Rouge`

in [page 2](http://www.nicolas.com/fr/18_409_9877_amiraldebeychevelle.htm): `2ème Vin, Saint-Julien, Rouge`

my code :

```
item ["appelation"] = res.select('.//div[@class="pro_col_right"]/div[@class="pro_blk_trans"]/div[@class="pro_blk_trans_titre"]/text()').re(r'\s*\w+\-\w+\-\w+|\w+\-\w+|\[^Rouge,Blanc]')
```

My regular expression couldn't find Margaux but it extracts Saint-Julien !!

Comment: What is the point of using a regular expression to extract something the exact form of which you already know?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need this but suppose `s` is your html file then this regex will find what you look for..

```
import re
m = re.search(r"\<div\ class=\"pro_blk_trans_titre\"\>(.*)\</div\>", s)
print(m.group(1).strip().encode("utf8"))

# page1: b'Margaux, Rouge'
# page2: b'2\xc3\xa8me Vin, Saint-Julien, Rouge'
```

Comment: thx @joente, i want to automate the extraction of **appelation** of win on this link [link](http://www.nicolas.com/fr/commander_bordeaux.html) by traversing each bottle of wine. the problem that's the structure of the pages of wine not similar(lookup to the links of Page1 and Page 2 ) so i want to use a regex which could find the **appelation** whatever the structure of my web page